# Optimize array to better fit 32-byte cache lines

Tags: c, arrays, caching

I am working on a program which accesses an `unsigned int` array in the following way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += 5) {
  // runs some code
  f(array[i]);
  // runs some code
  f(array[i+1]);
  // runs some code
  f(array[i+2]);
  // runs some code
  f(array[i+3]);
  // runs some code
  f(array[i+4]);
}
```

and the program runs on a device that embeds a cache with 32-byte cache line size.

Currently my array simply contains each value sequentially in a 'naive' fashion (i.e. `unsigned int array[60];`).

**One told me that I could improve my array alignment to fit the 32-byte cache lines. How should I proceed concretely?**

According to my understanding, it means ensuring that all 5 consecutive values are occupying a cache line, resulting in an unsigned int array of (60/5)*(32/4) = 96 elements with

```
array_new[0]; //contains array_old[0]
array_new[1]; //contains array_old[1]
array_new[2]; //contains array_old[2]
array_new[3]; //contains array_old[3]
array_new[4]; //contains array_old[4]
array_new[5]; //null
...
array_new[8]; // contains array_old[5]
...
array_new[95]; //contains array_old[59];
```

Would that indeed improve the performances in theory?

More generally, is it a good approach to ensure that all memory accesses executed within a loop fit a single cache line?

Comment: There is little evident in the code shown that would benefit from altering the start of `array`, other than due to chance effects. If the array is processed sequentially, its elements will be loaded into cache, used, and eventually cast out when other things use their cache sets. One minor consideration is that, if the array starts in the first half of a cache line, including the midpoint, it will occupy part or all of 8 cache lines (because it is 7.5 cache lines long). If it starts after the midpoint, it will occupy part or all of 9 cache lines, since a bit will extend into the next line.

Comment: Padding the array to leave blanks so that each five elements processed at a time are in their own cache sets is not likely to be productive. If there is some interaction between `array` and whatever other data `f` or `runs some code` uses, then there could be some cache issues. We would have to know more about `f` and `runs some code` to say. Other than that, processing 60 elements is fairly minor—unless this code is executed many, many times so that it is a performance issue, there is, on the face of it, not much of concern here.

Comment: Also, there is no need for all memory access executed with a single loop iteration to fit in a single cache line if the next iteration is going to continue consecutively.